# Would it be better to quote someone with their stage name or their real name?

Tags: quoting

I found a quote by an artist that I would like to use as an inspirational quote, however I don't know whether to reference them with their real name or their stage name. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmmm... that makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about English language or usage, it's about a writing convention, and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting this question up because this is about an issue which could arise in spoken English just as much as in written English. Not that written English should be off-topic anyway.